# Problem with super() using Multiple Inheritance with 2 Parent Classes and 1 Base Class

Tags: python-3.x

The error i'm having is:
print("Cód. Avião:", self.codigo_aviao)
AttributeError: 'Comprar_Bilhete' object has no attribute 'codigo_aviao'

I tried several options with super() but got no luck.

How can the Class "Comprar_Bilhete" grab the attribute 'codigo_aviao'?
I tried to put it in super() as a parameter but it gave me an error too!

```
class Pessoa():
  def __init__(self, nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade):
    self.nome = nome
    self.apelido = apelido
    self.idade = idade
    self.cartaocidadao = cc
    self.nacionalidade = nacionalidade

  def visualizar_pessoa(self):
    print("O", self.nome, "\b", self.apelido, "tem", self.idade, "anos, possui Cartão do Cidadão com o Nº", self.cartaocidadao, "e tem nacionalidade", self.nacionalidade, " \b.")


class Voo():
  def __init__(self, companhia, cod_voo, cod_aviao, data_partida, horario_partida, data_chegada, horario_chegada, aeroporto_partida, terminal_aeroporto_partida,
           aeroporto_chegada, terminal_aeroporto_chegada, tipo_de_bagagem):  # Construtor.
    self.companhia_aerea = companhia
    self.codigo_aviao = cod_aviao
    self.codigo_voo = cod_voo
    self.data_voo_partida = data_partida
    self.horario_partida = horario_partida
    self.data_voo_chegada = data_chegada
    self.horario_chegada = horario_chegada
    self.aeroporto_partida = aeroporto_partida
    self.terminal_aeroporto_partida = terminal_aeroporto_partida
    self.aeroporto_chegada = aeroporto_chegada
    self.terminal_aeroporto_chegada = terminal_aeroporto_chegada
    self.tipo_de_bagagem = tipo_de_bagagem

  def visualizar_dados_aviao(self):
    print("Companhia:", self.companhia_aerea, "\nCód. Avião:", self.codigo_aviao)


class Comprar_Bilhete(Pessoa, Voo):
  def __init__(self, nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade, companhia, cod_voo, cod_aviao, data_partida, horario_partida, data_chegada, horario_chegada,
           aeroporto_partida, terminal_aeroporto_partida, aeroporto_chegada, terminal_aeroporto_chegada, tipo_de_bagagem, preco):
    super().__init__(nome, apelido, idade, cc, nacionalidade)  # Usou-se o "super()" para tornar o código mais simples, em relação aos Atributos da Classe "Pessoa".
    self.preco_bilhete = preco

  def visualizar_custo_bilhete(self):
    print("O preço do bilhete de avião são", self.preco_bilhete, "euros.")

  def visualizar_pessoa(self):
    print("O", self.nome, "\b", self.apelido, "tem", self.idade, "anos.")

  def visualizar_dados_aviao(self):
    print("Cód. Avião:", self.codigo_aviao)


cliente1 = Comprar_Bilhete("Pedro", "Figueiredo", 49, 9876543, "Portuguesa", "Easyjet", "EJ1011", "FT4537", "27-08-2020", "23:05", "28-08-2020", "01:45",
                       "Humberto Delgado - Lisboa - PT", "Terminal 1", "Stansted - Hertfordshire - UK", "Terminal 3", "Bagagem de Porão + Mala de Mão", 275.48)

cliente1.visualizar_custo_bilhete()
print()

cliente1.visualizar_pessoa()
print()

cliente1.visualizar_dados_aviao()
print()
```

Comment: You should translate your code to english so it's clearer and easier to test.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is the *wrong pattern* here, but if you are going to use multiple inheritance, then *all your classes need to use `super`*. Your first call to `super` calls the `Pessoa.__init__`, but that's where the chain stops. Again, you should probably not be using multiple inheritance, `Compar_Bilhete` should use composition, it makes no sense to inherit from `Pessoa` and `Voo`

Comment: I tried to put super() in all the classes but still gives me the same error!